# How can I add state values to a default input value in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, render, accordion

I have an accordion that displays 3 inputs when clicked. A user can enter values and into those fields and then save them to state. When the accordion is collapsed... I am losing the input values. How can I get them from state for each input (if they are there?

[Github Repo](https://github.com/mmbmf1/backpackd-app/blob/static/src/AddBackpack/AddBackpack.js)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not be saving the values your users are entering anywhere. By using state you can save and repopulate values. Keep in mind there may be other stuff in your code causing your component to unload, but the code below should save the values just find.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class AddBackpack extends React.Component {
  // static contextType = ItemContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange({target}) {
    const {name, value} = target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {items} = this.context;
    const {handleChange} = this;

    return (
      <>
        <header>
          <h1>Create New Backpack</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <form id="record-backpack">
            <div className="form-section">
              <label htmlFor="backpack-title">Backpack Title</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="backpack-title"
                placeholder="Backpack One"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-section">
              <h3>Select Items for Backpack</h3>
              <div className="form-items-section">
                <div className="pack-items">
                  {Object.keys(items).map(function(category, key) {
                    return (
                      <div key={key} className={`${category}-category`}>
                        {/* <button></button> DO I NEED THIS TO EXPAND COLLAPSE?*/}
                        <h4>{`${category}`}</h4>
                        {items[category].map((value, i) => (
                          <>
                            <div className="item-inputs" key={i}>
                              <input type="radio" value={value} />
                              <label htmlFor={`${value}-item`}>{value}</label>
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                name={`${value}-name`}
                                id={`${value}-${i}-name`}
                                placeholder="Brand name or model of gear"
                                required
                                value={this.state[`${value}-name`]}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                name="backpack-size"
                                id={`${value}-${i}-size`}
                                placeholder="Size"
                                required
                                value={this.state[`${value}-name`]}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                              />
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                name="backpack-weight"
                                id={`${value}-${i}-weight`}
                                placeholder="Weight(g)"
                                required
                                value={this.state[`${value}-name`]}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                              />
                            </div>
                          </>
                        ))}{" "}
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="pack-list" id="">
              <h3>Backpack Summary</h3>
              <div className="pack-list-row" id="pack-weight">
                <p>Total Weight:</p>
              </div>
              <div className="pack-list-row" id="weights">
                <p>
                  0.00 kg
                  <br />
                  0.00 oz
                </p>
              </div>
              {/* <div className="pack-list-row" id="pack-functions"></div> */}
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It looks like I linked the wrong branch of the repo. The correct one ('static') is https://github.com/mmbmf1/backpackd-app/blob/static/src/AddBackpack/AddBackpack.js

Comment: The same goes for the page you linked. You're not saving the input values to state.

Comment: Line 49 with the handle item function is adding the user items to state. Maybe I'm not following?